# Generate MultiIndex DataFrame at different length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I need to initialize a multiIndex DataFrame from given data.

`id = ['a','b','c']` ;
`days = [2,5,4]`, which means, each id has its corresponding duration of days, i.e. 'a' has day 1,2; 'b' has day 1,..,5; and 'c' has day 1,...4. In another words, the days varies for each id.

And within each day, there are 4 periods, `prd = [0,1,2,3]`.
What I expect to have, is a MultiIndex of DataFrame for each id, at each day and each period.

```
   MultiIndex([('a',1,0),
               ('a',1,1),
               ('a',1,2),
               ('a',1,3),
               ('a',2,0),
               ('a',2,1),
               ('a',2,2),
               ('a',2,3),
               ('b',1,0),
               ('b',1,1),
               ('b',1,2),
               ...
               ('b',5,1),
               ('b',5,2),
               ('b',5,3),
               ('c',1,0),
               ('c',1,1),
               ('c',1,2),
               ...
               ('c',4,1),
               ('c',4,2),
               ('c',4,3),
],
names=['id','day','prd']
)
```

I tried to handle in python:
Because the days are different for different id, I generate two complete lists of id and days, by loop and list comprehension, and then `zip` them together to get the tuple pairs. And then I use `itertools.product()` to combine with period. But what I get is like

```
   [(('a',1),0),
    (('a',1),1),
    (('a',1),2),....]
```

If I use `pd.MultiIndex.from_product()`, I got similar results, that first two index are in a group, third one separated.

Since `product` won't help either way, the old fashion is to also stretch `prd` into long and complete list to match the other two fellas , and zip them at once.

I really want to know if there is a better way of generate index from beginning, better than such a long way of loops, list comprehension, zip and product to combine them together. Is there anything in Pandas can handle this case, other than native python data structures?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Create the combinations using list comprehension with `zip`:

```
id = ['a','b','c']
prd = [0,1,2,3]
days = [2,5,4]

result = [(idx, i, p) for d, idx in zip(days, id) for i in range(1, d+1) for p in prd]

print (pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(result))

MultiIndex([('a', 1, 0),
            ('a', 1, 1),
            ('a', 1, 2),
            ('a', 1, 3),
            ('a', 2, 0),
            ('a', 2, 1),
            ('a', 2, 2),
            ('a', 2, 3),
            ('b', 1, 0),
            ('b', 1, 1),
            ('b', 1, 2),
            ('b', 1, 3),
            ('b', 2, 0),
            ('b', 2, 1),
            ('b', 2, 2),
            ('b', 2, 3),
            ('b', 3, 0),
            ('b', 3, 1),
            ('b', 3, 2),
            ('b', 3, 3),
            ('b', 4, 0),
            ('b', 4, 1),
            ('b', 4, 2),
            ('b', 4, 3),
            ('b', 5, 0),
            ('b', 5, 1),
            ('b', 5, 2),
            ('b', 5, 3),
            ('c', 1, 0),
            ('c', 1, 1),
            ('c', 1, 2),
            ('c', 1, 3),
            ('c', 2, 0),
            ('c', 2, 1),
            ('c', 2, 2),
            ('c', 2, 3),
            ('c', 3, 0),
            ('c', 3, 1),
            ('c', 3, 2),
            ('c', 3, 3),
            ('c', 4, 0),
            ('c', 4, 1),
            ('c', 4, 2),
            ('c', 4, 3)],
           )
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you sooo much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and [`np.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) here. You can use this when dealing with large `id`, `prd`, `days`.

- You need to repeat `id` values w.r.t `days` and each element `len(prd)` times, we can use [`np.multiply`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html) here.
- You need to tile `prd` values by the total number of `days`, we can use [`np.sum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) here.
- Use [`pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html) to build desired output.

```
id = ['a','b','c']
prd = [0,1,2,3]
days = [2,5,4]

x = np.repeat(id,np.multiply(days, len(prd)))
y = np.concatenate([np.arange(1, i+1).repeat(len(prd)) for i in days])
z = np.tile(prd,np.sum(days))

pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([x,y,z])
# Equivalent to
# pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(np.c_[x,y,z].tolist())
#             x    y    z
#             |    |    |
#             V    V    V
MultiIndex([('a', '1', '0'),
            ('a', '1', '1'),
            ('a', '1', '2'),
            ('a', '1', '3'),
            ('a', '2', '0'),
            ('a', '2', '1'),
            ('a', '2', '2'),
            ('a', '2', '3'),
            ('b', '1', '0'),
            ('b', '1', '1'),
            ('b', '1', '2'),
            ('b', '1', '3'),
            ('b', '2', '0'),
            ('b', '2', '1'),
            ('b', '2', '2'),
            ('b', '2', '3'),
            ('b', '3', '0'),
            ('b', '3', '1'),
            ('b', '3', '2'),
            ('b', '3', '3'),
            ('b', '4', '0'),
            ('b', '4', '1'),
            ('b', '4', '2'),
            ('b', '4', '3'),
            ('b', '5', '0'),
            ('b', '5', '1'),
            ('b', '5', '2'),
            ('b', '5', '3'),
            ('c', '1', '0'),
            ('c', '1', '1'),
            ('c', '1', '2'),
            ('c', '1', '3'),
            ('c', '2', '0'),
            ('c', '2', '1'),
            ('c', '2', '2'),
            ('c', '2', '3'),
            ('c', '3', '0'),
            ('c', '3', '1'),
            ('c', '3', '2'),
            ('c', '3', '3'),
            ('c', '4', '0'),
            ('c', '4', '1'),
            ('c', '4', '2'),
            ('c', '4', '3')],
           )
```